# sed check for line before add

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I found a couple things that I tried, but didn't work.  Basically I need to modify /etc/export with a line, but want to check first to make sure the line isn't already there before appending the file.  It is for Opsworks, which every time you stop and start, run through all the scripts and would append the line to this file on every bootup. First one just lists the file wihout adding anything, second one adds it, every time.

```
awk -v s='/aiw ahost-name02(rw,no_root_squash,sync)' '/^all:/ && $0 !~ s "$" { $0 = $0 OFS s } 1' /etc/export
sed -i.bak '/^\/user @userhosts(rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)$/a /user ahost-name02(rw,no_root_squash,sync)' /etc/export
```

So I want to append to the existing line, and check on subsequent runs and not add if present the second line.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Like Cyrus said, but maybe a simplified export file, just 3 critical lines.

Comment: Overcomplicated IMHO.  Just  `grep -c` for the line, if == 0, add.

Comment: That is the sample input. Its the export file  /etc/export  Need to add a second server as listed. It has one line, want to add the second line. If I do the awk, it just prints the file without adding, if I do the second, then it adds the second line every time the server boots via Opsworks.

Comment: @Nic3500 `grep -c` is an antipattern, you want `grep -q` and examine the exit code instead of the output. `grep -Fxq foo file || echo foo >>file`

Comment: @tripleee, very nice! Here's a more DRY bash solution: `VAR="/aiw ahost-name02(rw,no_root_squash,sync)" && grep -Fxq "$VAR" /etc/export || echo $VAR >> /etc/export`

Comment: @AndriyMakukha You should quote the variable everywhere, also when you `echo` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an AWK solution. I changed the regex match operator `~ s "$"` to exact match `== s`:

```
awk -v s="/aiw ahost-name02(rw,no_root_squash,sync)" '$0 == s { fnd = 1 } 1; END { if (!fnd) print s }' /etc/export > export.tmp && mv export.tmp /etc/export
```

A little cumbersome, but it works.

**Another AWK solution:**

If you'd still prefer regex matching `~` over the exact match `==`, you'd need to correctly prepare regex expression out of your variable. Because parenthesis in your variable `s` would be considered as part of regex syntax during matching, not as characters.

Here I achieve this through a variable rgx:

```
awk -v s='/aiw ahost-name02(rw,no_root_squash,sync)' '
BEGIN { 
    rgx = s; 
    gsub(/[(]/, "[(]", rgx); 
    gsub(/[)]/, "[)]", rgx); 
} 
$0 ~ rgx { 
    fnd = 1 
} 
1; 
END { 
    if (!fnd) 
        print s 
}' /etc/export > export.tmp && mv export.tmp /etc/export
```

Comment: `1 { print }` is commonly and idiomatically abbreviated to just `1;`

Comment: The variable worked. The only thing now is that is asks to overwrite the file, and I can't seem to automate that last step, is there an option I can add?

Comment: @acdii, instead of `mv export.tmp /etc/export` you could use `mv -f export.tmp /etc/export`. It will force overwriting without asking.

Comment: That appears to have worked, too bad I didn't see this before I ran the job as it is hanging and pretty sure at this point in the recipe. I will rerun the install and see if it completes now. I did it manually and it worked.